# Why can't I forward declare pointer structs?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I am using a slightly obscure sound library called SDL_mixer. GCC is complaining about me forward declaring a pointer struct? What am I doing wrong?

```
Mix_Music **music; // music[2] must be a pointer to fit any random file
music = new Mix_Music[3];
music[2] = Mix_LoadMUS("fire.ogg");
```

GCC returns:

```
     ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
    xxx.cpp||In function 'int SDL_main(int, char**)':|
    xxx.cpp|28|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'Mix_Music {aka struct _Mix_Music}'|
   SDL_mixer.h|131|error: forward declaration of 'Mix_Music {aka struct _Mix_Music}'|
    ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

edit: I need the struct to be dynamically allocated, as thousands of files might be loaded. Stack memory won't do.

Comment: `Mix_Music* music[3]; music[2] = Mix_LoadMUS("fire.ogg");`

Comment: Typical stack is around a megabyte. That's 128k pointers.

Comment: I'd hardly call SDL_mixer "obscure"!

Comment: Not sure how obscure it is, but using a reserved name isn't cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `new Mix_Music[3]` the compiler needs to know how big each object is in order to know how much space to allocate. A forward declaration doesn't give it that information.

You probably want `new Mix_Music*[3]`. Although stack allocation might work, and `std::array` or `std::vector` would make things better.

Comment: Then how could I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: See added paragraph.

Comment: Stack is fine for normal operation, what do you know! Thanks guys.